# WordPress: Prevent Content Field from Saving on Save

Tags: php, wordpress

When an admin saves a post from my custom post type `jobs`, i do not want the content field(the large 'description' field) from saving.

To explain - when an admin saves a post from the `jobs` post type all the custom fields, date field etc. should save but the standard content field should stay the same without being saved.

I've found the `pre_post_update` hook, but i do not know what to do now.

This is my code so far.

```
add_action( 'pre_post_update', 'prefix_prevent_job_description_admin_save' );
function prefix_prevent_job_description_admin_save( $post_id, $data ) {
   
   if ( 'jobs' !== get_post_type( $post_id ) ) return;

   // Here i should probably use the $data array to get the content and prevent it from saving, but i do not know how to go from here.

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is happening currently to the post content that you don't want to happen?

Comment: I only want the post content to be saved from a frontend form i made. So it should be possible to save the post from the admin dashboard, but the content field should not update(as it creates markup problems).

Answer (score 1):

**A solution that comes to my mind**

To do this, you must allow WordPress to update the relevant post, then manually update the old values.

The [`post_updated` [see also]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/) action provides a complete solution for you. Its realization form and logic are as follows.

[image]

#### For your code:

```
add_action('post_updated','after_update_post_without_update_desc',10,3);

function after_update_post_without_update_desc($postID, $after, $before)
 {
    if( 'jobs' !== get_post_type( $post_id ) ) return;

    if( $after->post_content != $before->post_content )
    {
       $after->post_content = $before->post_content;
       wp_update_post($after, false, false);
    }       
 }
```

As a more logical solution, the filter proposed by "[@Jasper B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65632770/11151040)" can be used.
I think this will be much more true. (saves you from doing extra queries)

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data_content' , '99', 2 );

function filter_post_data_content( $data , $postarr ) {
    if( 'jobs' !== $data['post_type'] ) return;
    // Remove post_content form the data
    unset($data['post_content']);
    return $data;
}
```

**Note**: You should test it works fine with `unset()`. (I am not sure)

To be sure, you can try it out with an extra query as below.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data_content' , '99', 2 );

function filter_post_data_content( $data , $postarr ) {
    $post = get_post($postarr['ID']);
    if( 'jobs' !== $post->post_type ) return;
    $data['post_content'] = $post->post_content;
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot this worked. I just have one problem with it: Now it prevents the content field to be saved everywhere. I only want it to not be saved in the admin dashboard. I've made my own frontend submission system with wp_update_post where i still want it to update.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it with a filter instead of an action, i think you can do this with the this filter wp_insert_post_data

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_data/